# Big O notation problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

what is wrong with my solution.
The problem and my solution is following:

Q: $f(n) = 3n\ln(n!) + (n^2+3)\ln(n)$ what is Big O of $f(n)$

1. $n!$ is $O(n^n)$ then $\ln(n!)$ is $O(n\ln(n))$
2. $3n$ is $O(n)$ by using the theorem for polynomial functions.
3. $3n\ln(n!)$ is $O(n^2\ln(n))$
4. $n^2 + 3$ is $O(n^2)$
5. $\ln(n)$ is $O(n)$
6. $(n^2+3)\ln(n)$ is $O(n^3)$
7. $f(n)$ is $O(n^3)$ since $\max(n^3, n^2\ln(n))$ is $n^3$

I am somewhat confident on my solution but the book says $f(n)$ is $O(n^2\ln(n))$

Comment: In step $6$, $(n^2 + 3) \ln(n)$ is $O(n^2 \ln(n))$, which is tighter than your $O(n^3)$ bound.

Comment: $(n^2+3)\times \ln (n)$ is $O(n^2\times \ln n)$.

Comment: Note that big $O$ notation is not really unique. You can take larger than actual growth. And the approximation of $\log n$ to $n$ is considered to be quite naive in common sense.

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys.
But, the theorem of product says $f_1*f_2(x)$ is $O(g_1*g_2(x))$.
In the case of the step 6, ln(x) is O(x) not itself.

Comment: @SeungHwanKim In step 5, $\ln n$ is also $O(\ln n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for comments I fix my problem.

The key point is $ln(n)$ is $O(ln(n))$

$∃ C, k:$ any $x >k (ln(n) <= Cln(n))$

k = 1, C can be any number greater than 1.

So $ln(n)$ is $O(ln(n))$

Comment: I hope your own proof here also convinces you that in fact $f(x)$ is $O(f(x))$ for any function $f$. This should be considered a triviality any time you use it

Comment: Thank you for your comment.